# How to build multiple maven modules project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I have Module based maven project. Project structure is like that :

- Prarent project name is - `Parent1`

That has Three childs :

- Child 1 project name is - `Children1`
- Child 2 project name is - `Children2`
- Child 3 project name is - `Children3`

So, When i am change some js, css or images in `Children2` then i have to build `Parent1` project , so it takes too much time. so Is there any way to build only `Children2` project and see new changes ?

Comment: if its all maven project then, `Childern2` would have its own `pom.xml` right? You can directly invoke that pom to build just `Children2`. what is the issue in that?

Comment: Yes `Children2` project has it's own pom.xml file but when i build this pom file i am not able to view new changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the command line just switch to the directory containing the project.

With an IDE just selet the project in question.